# JsonConvert and NServiceBus namespace conflict

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, .net-4.5, nservicebus

We have a project that was using Json.Net and JsonConvert.

It worked just fine until we decided to change our NServiceBus serialization to Json.

Now we get an error saying that JsonConvert is an internal class and "cannot be accessed here".

Looking at the generated code, it looks like NServiceBus embeds JsonConvert in its code.  This embedded code has the Newtonsoft.Json namespace but makes the JsonConvert class internal.

**Is there a way to tell the complier use the NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert from assembly Newtonsoft.Json.dll and not in NServiceBus.Core.dll for a specific class?**

Comment: Did you tried to do a fully qualifiedd call? Ex: NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert convert = new .... ?

Comment: @Gusman - Yes.  The problem is that both are called Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.  They are just in different assemblies.  Visual Studio finds the one that was altered by NServiceBus first.  (In my opinion if you are going to embed a library and alter it, you should change the namespace so this does not happen.)

Comment: Indeed they should did it. As a last Hope, you can load manually the desired assembly and then use CreateInstance to create the serializer, but you will call its methods through reflection because you cannot do a cast by the collided namespaces.

Comment: I cannot replicate this. can you upload a repro somewhere?

Comment: @Simon - The app in question is huge.  And we were only using JSON to serialize for logging.  We abandoned the JSON library because it was not worth the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
You need to use `extern alias`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx